# Python: How to update the calls of a third class to the overriden method of the original class?

Tags: python

```
class ThirdPartyA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    def ...():
    ...
-------------------
from xxx import ThirdPartyA

class ThirdPartyB(object):
    def a(self):
        ...
        #call to ThirdPartyA
        ....

    def b(self):
        ...
        #call to ThirdPartyA
        ...

    def c(self):
        ...
        #call to ThirdPartyA
        ...
-----------------------------------
from xxx import ThirdPartyA

class MyCodeA(ThirdPartyA):
    def __init__(self):
        # overriding code
```

When overriding the `__init__` method of A class, how could I instruct B class that it should call MyCodeA instead of ThirdPartyA in all its methods?

The real code is here:

[CLass Geoposition: ThirdPartyA](https://github.com/philippbosch/django-geoposition/blob/4d69d852d80d45ec46b5ed753e40c85348850f5d/geoposition/__init__.py)

[Class GeopositionField: ThirdPartyB](https://github.com/philippbosch/django-geoposition/blob/4d69d852d80d45ec46b5ed753e40c85348850f5d/geoposition/fields.py)

My override to class Geoposition so it returns max 5 decimal digits:

```
class AccuracyGeoposition(Geoposition):

    def __init__(self, latitude, longitude):
        if isinstance(latitude, float) or isinstance(latitude, int):
            latitude = '{0:.5f}'.format(latitude)
        if isinstance(longitude, float) or isinstance(longitude, int):
            longitude = '{0:.5f}'.format(longitude)

        self.latitude = Decimal(latitude)
        self.longitude = Decimal(longitude)
```

Comment: you should have an instance of `OverridenA`, that is called in the methods of `B`. Calling `A().a()` seems strange to me.

Comment: Probably my semantics are not accurate. This means I have to override all B methods?

Comment: what is your real code, what do you try to achieve.

Comment: Defining a subclass that overrides one or more methods doesn't change the parent class at all. If you want an instance of `B` to use an extended version of `A`, then its `__init__` method should take a reference to the correct (sub)class of `A` to use.

Comment: @Daniel I am trying to override a class of a third party module. I have updated the question with the actual code.

Comment: The updated version is better, but you probably could (and should) have given us a lot less code. Read [MCVE](stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidance on what to post.

Comment: @abarnet Thank you for your guidance and help, I will update the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your updated code, I think what you're *trying* to do is change `GeopositionField. to_python()` so that it returns `AccuracyGeoposition` values instead of `Geoposition` values.

There's no way to do that directly; the code in `GeopositionField` explicitly says it wants to construct a `Geoposition`, so that's what happens.

The cleanest solution is to subclass `GeopositionField` as well, so you can wrap that method:

```
class AccuracyGeopositionField(GeopositionField):
    def topython(self, value):
        geo = super(AccuracyGeopositionField, self).topython(value)
        return AccuracyGeoposition(geo.latitude, geo.longitude)
```

---

If creating a `Geoposition` and then re-wrapping the values in an `AccuracyGeoposition` is insufficient (because accuracy has already been lost), you might be able to pre-process things before calling the super method as well/instead. For example, if the way it deals with `list` is not acceptable (I realize that's not true here, but it serves as a simple example), but everything else you can just let it do its thing and wrap the result, you could do this:

```
class AccuracyGeopositionField(GeopositionField):
    def topython(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, list):
            return AccuracyGeoposition(value[0], value[1])
        geo = super(AccuracyGeopositionField, self).topython(value)
        return AccuracyGeoposition(geo.latitude, geo.longitude)
```

If worst comes to worst, you may have to reimplement the entire method (maybe by copying, pasting, and modifying its code), but hopefully that will rarely come up.

---

There are hacky alternatives to this. For example, you could monkeypatch the module to globally replace the `Geoposition` class with your `AccuracyGeoposition` class But, while that may save some work up front, you're almost certain to be unhappy with it when you're debugging things later. Systems that are designed for aspect-oriented programming (which is basically controlled monkeypatching) are great, but trying to cram it into systems that were designed to resist it will give you headaches.

Comment: Indeed, my question rose when I realised -during my search for this issue- that monkeypatching should better be the last option. Thank you again, I did not really mean to be confusing.

Comment: @rara_tiru: This is a problem that comes up whenever a library designer doesn't anticipate your uses. Sometimes you can just fork and modify the library to do what you want, or make it easier to wrap up; sometimes you can even ask the upstream author to do it. When you can't, you end up either needing to duplicate code, or monkeypatch. Neither one is really good, it's just a matter of picking the less bad for your case.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your real code works like your example—that is, every method of `B` creates a new `A` instance just to call a method on it and discard it—well, that's a very weird design, but if it makes sense for your use case, you can make it work.

The key here is that classes are first-class objects. Instead of hardcoding `A`, store the class you want as a member of the `B` instance, like this:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, aclass=A):
        self.aclass = aclass

    def a(self):
        self.aclass().a()
```

Now, you just create a `B` instance with your subclass:

```
b = B(OverriddenA)
```

---

Your edited version does a *different* strange thing: instead of constructing a new `A` instance each time to call methods on it, you're calling class methods on `A` itself. Again, this is probably not what you want—but, if it is, you can do it:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, aclass=A):
        self.aclass = aclass

    def a(self):
        self.aclass.a()
```

---

However, more likely you don't really want either of these. You want to take an `A` *instance* at construction time, store it, and use it repeatedly. Like this:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, ainstance):
        self.ainstance = ainstance

    def a(self):
        self.ainstance.a()

b1 = B(A())
b2 = B(OverriddenA())
```

---

If this all seems abstract and hard to understand… well, that's because we're using meaningless names like `A`, `B`, and `OverriddenA`. If you tell us the actual types you're thinking about, or just plug those types in mechanically, it should make a lot more sense.

For example:

```
class Vehicle(object):
    def move(self):
        print('I am a vehicle, and I am moving')

class Operator(object):
    def __init__(self, vehicle):
        self.vehicle = vehicle
    def move(self):
        print('I am moving my vehicle')
        self.vehicle.move()

class Car(object):
    def move(self):
        print('I am a car, and I am driving')

driver = Operator(Car())
driver.move()
```

Comment: Thanx indeed for your realtime update and explanation. My question was horrible, sorry. This is a third party module where I am trying to override the init method of one if its fundamental classes, I have updated the question and also added the actual code.